# Exception on JDBC IAM connect to Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc

I try to make JDBC connect to Amazon Redshift using IAM account.

As described in: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/generating-iam-credentials-configure-jdbc-odbc.html
paragraph #3, I use URL:

```
jdbc:redshift:iam://redshift-cluster-vms.my_cluster.amazonaws.com:5439/dev?AccessKeyID=AKI*********DD&SecretAccessKey=tGv********************mQU
```

and Java code:

```
String connectString ="jdbc:redshift:iam://redshift-cluster-vms.my_cluster.amazonaws.com:5439/dev?AccessKeyID=AKI*********DD&SecretAccessKey=tGv********************mQU";
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectString);
```

The JDBC driver version: redshift-jdbc42-2.1.0.7.jar

It throws the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: FATAL: user "IAM:SSh" does not exist
        at com.amazon.redshift.util.RedshiftException.getSQLException(RedshiftException.java:56)
        at com.amazon.redshift.Driver.connect(Driver.java:336)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace. The "Caused by" indicates you haven't posted the full chain of exceptions.

Comment: Actually it is full stack. Upper was our custom exception caused by this one